# Is it possible to make an interactive map with drone imagery and can we use the application as google maps works?

Tags: google-maps, unity-game-engine, gis

Geo-referenced map with an size of 2.7gb (.tiff) format.to display into tiles into android application respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.
First generate tiles with QGIS -> QTiles plugin, after that upload these tiles on web file server and tiles will be available to load on android application.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can generate tiles from tiff file using http://www.gdal.org/. After conversion you get index.html with the tiles.Now its onto you how you can convert it into android application our serve from web application to your android application.